# how to insert NSDate in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsdate, insertion

HELLO i am trying to insert Current date in my database table
 i have a column dateVisited of type datetime

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"]; //this is the sqlite's format
NSDate *stringTime = [NSDate date];
NSString *formattedDateStringTime = [formatter stringFromDate:stringTime];

sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into AnwaltHistory (id,dateVisited) values (%d,'%@')",Id formattedDateStringTime];

NSLog(@"%@",sqlStr);
BOOL Res = [appDelegate InsUpdateDelData: sqlStr];
if (Res)
{
   NSLog(@"The Following instrunction is excuted successfully !");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"The Following instrunction Failed to execute !");
}
```

the statement executes successfully but when i actually go and check the table it says invalid date... i dont know why 
as i have printed sqlstr i copy paste from the console and paste it in sqlite and run it manually it runs perfectly fine and has the actual date....
can any one guide me where i am mistaken :S.......
please

Comment: can you run
`sqlite> .schema AnwaltHistory` 
and paste the output?

Comment: when i myself manually run the query on db interface
Insert into AnwaltHistory (id,dateVisited) values (87403,datetime())
or
Insert into AnwaltHistory (id,dateVisited) values (123,2010/04/07 01:49:55)


it is inserted fine (the above two queries are the result of my sqlStr) but doesnt work automated, works fine while manual.

Comment: sqlite does not have a datetime type. what is the schema of the AnwaltHistory table?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
"Insert into AnwaltHistory (id,dateVisited) values (%d,datetime())",Id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I tried
sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into AnwaltHistory (id,dateVisited) values (%d,datetime())",Id];
On debugging i figured out it says sqlStr is invalid. 
and i used NSLog to see whats in sqlStr.
Insert into AnwaltHistory (id,dateVisited) values (87403,datetime())
which is fine and the statement executed successfully 
but when i explore the db it shows id but the time is invalid again
and then i ran the sqlStr manually it is inserted perfectly with no error.
where i am mistaken :S
And sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
double dateVisited = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; //now
// save dateVisited to your 'dateVisited' field
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documents](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the DateTime on SQLITE should be in ISO8601 format (AKA: a string of ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"))

Therefore, to store the date, you should format your date string, below is a code to help you with this:

```
NSDate *SourceDate = [NSDate date];  // Or whatever NSDATE you like...
NSDateFormatter *MyDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[MyDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSString *SQLiteQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into YourTable(YourDateField) values ('%@')", [MyDateFormatter stringFromDate:SourceDate]];
```

This should do it, give's a shout if you need more help,

Cheers
H